# Google Analytics 4 Data API use order by

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-data-api

I started using Google Analytics 4 Data API and downloaded the PHP library to create the requests. I have been playing a little and my request is working good so far, but when I need to sort it I don't know exactly how to pass that data, I have been trying many ways but no luck.

Check **"orderBys"** data, there I supposed to pass orderType and dimensionName to filter by dimensions date so it should be something like **"ordertype" => ALPHANUMERIC** and **"dimensionName => "date"**

Any tip would be much appreciated :)

```
$response = $client->runReport([
          'property' => 'properties/' . $property_id,
          'dateRanges' => [
              new DateRange([
                  'start_date' => '7daysAgo',
                  'end_date' => 'yesterday',
              ]),
          ],
          'dimensions' => [new Dimension(
              ['name' => 'day']
          ),
          ],
          'metrics' => [

            new Metric(['name' => 'newUsers']),

            new Metric(['name' => 'active7DayUsers']),
          
          ],

          'orderBys' => [],
      ]);
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This works for me:

Note that is used the **V1beta** package

```
use Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\BetaAnalyticsDataClient;


$response = $client->runReport([

    // ...

    'orderBys' => [
        new OrderBy([
            'dimension' => new OrderBy\DimensionOrderBy([
                'dimension_name' => 'month', // your dimension here
                'order_type' => OrderBy\DimensionOrderBy\OrderType::ALPHANUMERIC
            ]),
            'desc' => false,
        ]),
    ],
]);
```

I had similar struggle, the documentation is really bad.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. it worked perfectly, how did you find out about it? would be nice to read more about that.

Comment: @Daniel 2 hours of reading through the package source, the data api doc and a lot trial and error

Comment: I hope it's OK to leave this comment here, even though it doesn't directly relate to the question. I've spent hours trying to solve this in Python and kept ending up back here. I eventually worked out the syntax, so just wanted to share it in case anyone else takes the same route as me: `order_bys = [OrderBy(dimension = OrderBy.DimensionOrderBy(dimension_name = "date"))]` and make sure to import OrderBy - Thanks anyway @btx your answer helped a lot!

Comment: It worked thanks. I just had to import the namespace - use Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\OrderBy;

Comment: i wonder which bright engineer from google has simplified the previous, UA library code from smth like: orderby='-ga:month', to `'orderBys' => [
        new OrderBy([
            'dimension' => new OrderBy\DimensionOrderBy([
                'dimension_name' => 'month', // your dimension here
                'order_type' => OrderBy\DimensionOrderBy\OrderType::ALPHANUMERIC
            ]),
            'desc' => false,
        ]),
    ],`

Comment: @devplayer Due to the fact, that the API library is available in many languages, I guess its some code that is being converted to the target languages. Maybe it was easier to realize this way. In the end, the main problem is, that the documentation is garbage